# View AVG Task Execution Time in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I run the following task in Snowflake to see which queries are candidates for inefficiency improvements:

```
select datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) as second, *
  from table(information_schema.task_history())
  where state != 'SCHEDULED'
  order by datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) desc;
```

However, I frequently see the seconds a query took to run change from day to day. How can I modify this query in Snowflake to get all the historical runs from task history and average their seconds to get a fuller picture with less variance?

The documentation says it pulls the last 7 days but in practice it is only pulling the last 2 days based on the output's scheduled_time (each of my tasks run every 12 hours). I'd like to get the average seconds each task took over the last 30 days and sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The documentation says it pulls the last 7 days **but in practice it is only pulling the last 2 days based on the output's scheduled_time** (each of my tasks run every 12 hours).*

[Task history](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html)

> `RESULT_LIMIT => integer`
>
> A number specifying the maximum number of rows returned by the function.
>
> Default: 100.

To get more rows the `RESULT_LIMIT` should be defined:

```
select datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) as second, *
from table(information_schema.task_history(RESULT_LIMIT =>10000))
where state != 'SCHEDULED'
order by datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) desc;
```

---

[ACCOUNT_USAGE.TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_history.html) provides data for the last 365 days.

```
SELECT datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) as second, *
FROM snowflake.account_usage.task_history
WHERE state != 'SCHEDULED'
ORDER BY datediff(second,scheduled_time,query_start_time) DESC;
```